# Apache2 malicious put requests?

Tags: apache, put

I have a server running apache2 which seems to become unresponsive every few weeks for no apparent reason. I've enable apache status so that I can try and trace down the issue.

I can see lots of PUT requests. e.g

PUT /ppdhx91519.txt HTTP/1.1
PUT /nmfzs66661.txt HTTP/1.1
PUT /sgcmg28806.txt HTTP/1.1
PUT /fhpbt57511.txt HTTP/1.1
PUT /fdbdl39153.txt HTTP/1.1
PUT /ali.txt HTTP/1.1
etc.

Can someone suggest what theses are and if they are usual or something more malicious?

Answer (score 0):

If Apache's server-status says that all apache workers are busy, this is a "slow" attack. You can read [here](https://community.qualys.com/blogs/securitylabs/2011/11/02/how-to-protect-against-slow-http-attacks) about it and how to fight it. The most popular way is to use `mod_reqtimeout`, `mod_qos` or `mod_security`.